# Data remains unconverted when stripped of unnecessary things

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, plotly-dash

I want to extract all a `DatePickerRange` of the library `dash_core_components` but after stripping of things unecessaries the compiler tells me that there are remains that he can not use:

```
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import dash_core_components as dcc
import datetime as dt

import pickle

from ..server import app

@app.callback(
    # Output('output-container-button', 'children'),
    Output('articles', 'children'),
    [Input('button', 'n_clicks'), 
    Input('my-date-picker-range', 'start_date_value'),
    Input('my-date-picker-range', 'end_date_value')],
    [State('input-box', 'value')])
def update_search(n_clicks, value, start_date_value, end_date_value):
    f = pickle.load(open("dashboard/data-mm/google-nlu-khazaradze.p", "rb"))
    # let's filter f according to value
    print(start_date_value)
    start_date = dt.datetime.strptime(start_date_value.split(' ')[0], '%Y-%m-%d')
    end_date = dt.datetime.strptime(end_date_value.split(' ')[0], '%Y-%m-%d')
```

But answered the compiler:

```
File "C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\richmond2\dashboard\callbacks\search.py", line 20, in update_search
start_date = dt.datetime.strptime(start_date_value.split(' ')[0], '%Y-%m-%d')
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\_strptime.py", line 577, in _strptime_datetime
tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\_strptime.py", line 362, in _strptime
data_string[found.end():])
ValueError: unconverted data remains: T11:55:55.226148
```

Here it is what contains start_date_value:

```
2020-01-28T11:55:55.226148
```

Which is the same as `start_date.split ( '') [0]`:

Comment: There is a T that seperates the date from the time. You have to do start_date.split("T")[0] and end_date_value.split("T")[0] respectively.

Comment: Why are you using a pickle and not a json? (Do you have a choice in the matter?)